# UIAlertview won't log result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I want to log if the user pressed OK on my `alertView`, but it's doing nothing... This is my check:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) { NSLog(@"user pressed OK"); }
}
```

Also it's in my `@interface`:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And here's my `alertView`:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oeps..."
                                            message:@"This is just a random message."
                                            delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Does anyone see the problem? I tried to do an `NSLog` outside of the `if buttonIndex` but that won't be logged too..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of delegate being nil,assign your delegate as self

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oeps..."
                                        message:@"This is just a random message."
                                        delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your delegate you passed the delegate to nil. pass it to **self** thats whay this is happening...

like this

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oeps..."
                                            message:@"This is just a random message."
                                            delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```